# Getting the "path" of connected/disconnected USB HID devices in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, usb, hid

As a flightsim enthusiast, I'm making my own cockpit hardware. I interface this hardware with my computer(s) using the USB HID interface (HW based on PIC microcontrollers). All hardware has the same VID/PID, and the Product Descriptor string is "FMGS HW Device" (fyi: FMGS is the name of the Airbus A320 simulator software I'm using).

On startup, my application scans all the USB devices and only puts the ones with my "VID/PID/Product Descriptor" combination in a Dictionary. As key, I'm using the "DevicePath" that I retrieve via the PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA structure with a call to SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail (setupapi.dll).

Below is a small code extract that shows the core of this operation - just so you get the idea:

```
// Retrieving the detailDataBuffer
SetupApi.SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(deviceInfoSet, ref deviceInterfaceData, detailDataBuffer, bufferSize, ref bufferSize, IntPtr.Zero);
 
// Skip over cbsize (4 bytes) to get the address of the devicePathName
var pDevicePath = new IntPtr(detailDataBuffer.ToInt32() + 4);

// Get the String containing the devicePath
AddDevice(Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pDevicePath));
```

This DevicePath has the following format:

\?\hid#vid_04d8&pid_003f#9&599cfdc&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}

**Question 1:**
I can clearly see the VID/PID part (vid_04d8&pid_003f) and the HidGuid (4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030), but what is the part with "9&599cfdc&0&0000"? Is that unique for every device? With other words, isn't there a risk that 2 of my devices have exactly the same DevicePath?

Now I also want to detect if devices are connected/disconnected while the application is running. If device are disconnected, I need to remove them from my Dictionary. If devices are connected, I need to put them in my Dictionary and start communicating with them.

I'm using the "WMI method" (I know there is also a WM_DEVICECHANGE method in WndProc, not sure what is better?). Below is the code (not finished, but works so far).

```
    private void DeviceInsertedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DeviceInsertEvent");
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

        foreach(PropertyData p in instance.Properties )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{p.Name} = {p.Value }");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"{instance.Properties["Dependent"].Value }");
    }

    private void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DeviceRemovedEvent");
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

        foreach (PropertyData p in instance.Properties)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"{p.Name} = {p.Value }");
        }

        Debug.WriteLine($"{instance.Properties["Dependent"].Value}");
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        try
        {
            WqlEventQuery insertQuery = new WqlEventQuery();
            insertQuery.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
            insertQuery.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            insertQuery.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
            ManagementEventWatcher insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertQuery);
            insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
            insertWatcher.Start();

            WqlEventQuery removeQuery = new WqlEventQuery();
            removeQuery.EventClassName = "__InstanceDeletionEvent";
            removeQuery.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            removeQuery.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
            ManagementEventWatcher removeWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(removeQuery);
            removeWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceRemovedEvent);
            removeWatcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"backgroundWorker_DoWork Exception: {ex}");
        }

        while (true) ;
    }
```

I am not a WMI expert, so I have honestly no clue what I'm doing (still learning) - just got the code from several google searches. I discovered that "instance.Properties["Dependent"].Value" gives me also some kind of DevicePath, with the below format.

\DESKTOP-HANS\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="HID\VID_04D8&PID_003F\9&2E7AE93E&0&0000"

I see the same VID/PID combination, and the unknown "9&2E7AE93E&0&0000" part that I asked for in **Question 1**. So basically, with some string-manipulations, I could reconstruct the same DevicePath that I'm using as the key in my Dictionary.

**Question 2:**
Is there another way to discover device connect/disconnect events that give me the same DevicePath as returned by SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail?

Comment: Just found an interesting article that explains in full detail the arrival/removed event through WM_DEVICECHANGE. Please find it here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal. This event provides a structure DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE with member dbcc_name which gives DevicePath in same format as SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail. I haven't tried this approach, but will definitely do. The WMI method works (see below), but it feels not very responsive when I stress test my device at 1 message per ms. Just curious to see how WM_DEVICECHANGE works.

Comment: HI Hans, we are looking for someone to do a bit of HID programming for us - interested?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been continuing with the above concept, and it works as a charm. I changed the code in the below, and now my USB devices are nicely added or removed dynamically when my application is running. The "puzzling part" is in constructing the correct DevicePath format in the DeviceCreatedEvent and DeviceRemovedEvent.

_stringHidGuid is obtained in the constructer of my UsbServer. I need it a few times, so I created a private member for it. It is a string with the format (already added the '#' and curly brackets):

```
#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
```

I use this to "construct" the DevicePath based on the "Dependent" value I'm getting from the WMI __InstanceCreationEvent and __InstanceDeletionEvent.

_DeviceArrivedWatcher and _DeviceRemovedWatcher are another 2 private members of type ManagementEventWatcher to keep the notifiers when initializing the code. _vid and _pid contain my VID and PID.

Below is the full code extract.

```
    private void DeviceCreatedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

        // Describes the logical device connected to the Universal Serial Bus (USB) controller.
        string path = (string)instance.Properties["Dependent"].Value;

        // Check if it is our device
        int start = path.IndexOf($"HID\\\\VID_{_vid:X4}&PID_{_pid:X4}");
        if (start != -1)
        {
            // Create the DevicePath to be used in UsbServer
            path = path.Substring(start, path.Length - start - 1).Replace("\\\\", "#");
            path = string.Concat("\\\\?\\", path, _stringHidGuid);
            Debug.WriteLine($"DeviceCreatedEvent for {path}");
            AddDevice(path);
        }
    }

    private void DeviceRemovedEvent(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManagementBaseObject instance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent["TargetInstance"];

        // Describes the logical device connected to the Universal Serial Bus (USB) controller.
        string path = (string)instance.Properties["Dependent"].Value;

        // Check if it is our device
        int start = path.IndexOf($"HID\\\\VID_{_vid:X4}&PID_{_pid:X4}");
        if (start != -1)
        {
            // Create the DevicePath to be used in UsbServer
            path = path.Substring(start, path.Length - start - 1).Replace("\\\\", "#");
            path = string.Concat("\\\\?\\", path, _stringHidGuid);
            Debug.WriteLine($"DeviceRemovedEvent for {path}");
            RemoveDevice(path);
        }
    }

    private void AddDeviceArrivedHandler()
    {
        try
        {
            var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

            var q = new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
            q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            q.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";

            _deviceArrivedWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
            _deviceArrivedWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceCreatedEvent;
            _deviceArrivedWatcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"AddDeviceArrivedHandler() Exception: {ex}");
            if (_deviceArrivedWatcher != null)
                _deviceArrivedWatcher.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void AddDeviceRemovedHandler()
    {
        try
        {
            var scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

            var q = new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName = "__InstanceDeletionEvent";
            q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            q.Condition = @"TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";

            _deviceRemovedWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
            _deviceRemovedWatcher.EventArrived += DeviceRemovedEvent;
            _deviceRemovedWatcher.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"AddDeviceRemovedHandler() Exception: {ex}");
            if (_deviceRemovedWatcher != null)
                _deviceRemovedWatcher.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void DeviceNotificationsStop()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_deviceArrivedWatcher != null)
                _deviceArrivedWatcher.Stop();
            if (_deviceRemovedWatcher != null)
                _deviceRemovedWatcher.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"DeviceNotificationStop() Exception: {ex}");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a best source of knowledge about this topic I can recommend [USB Complete
The Developer's Guide](http://janaxelson.com/usbc.htm) book, [USBView](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview) and [HClient](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/hid/hclient) official MS samples on GitHub.

`\?\hid#vid_04d8&pid_003f#9&599cfdc&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}` is a so called device interface path. Its format is not documented by MS (so could be changes at any time) and its not safe to parse it. Every device could provide several interfaces to interact with it. For example every USB HID device also have interface with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE` - `{A5DCBF10-6530-11D2-901F-00C04FB951ED}`.

There are two main Win32 APIs exist to query for connected devices: [SetupDi*](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/setupapi/) (defined in `SetupAPI.h`) and [CM_*](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/) (defined in `cfgmgr32.h`). You can also use WMI but I not familiar with it.

Regarding how to convert device interface path to VID/PID:

You can use `CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW` (or `SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW`) with `DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` param to request "device instance identifier". After that you can open that device via `CM_Locate_DevNodeW` (or `SetupDiGetClassDevsW`) with device instance id that you got and query `DEVPKEY_Device_HardwareIds` (string list) property on it. And returned stuff [you can parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/install/standard-usb-identifiers) because its documented:

```
Each interface has a device ID of the following form:
USB\VID_v(4)&PID_d(4)&MI_z(2)

Where:
  v(4) is the 4-digit vendor code that the USB committee assigns to the vendor.
  d(4) is the 4-digit product code that the vendor assigns to the device.
  z(2) is the interface number that is extracted from the bInterfaceNumber field of the interface descriptor.
```

PS: Found WMI example code with VID/PID filtering for in a book I mentioned:

```cpp
void FindDevice()
{
    const String deviceIdString = @”USB\VID_0925&PID_150C”;
    _deviceReady = false;
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(“root\\CIMV2”, “SELECT PNPDeviceID FROM Win32_PnPEntity”);
    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get()) {
        if (queryObj[“PNPDeviceID”].ToString().Contains(deviceIdString)) {
            _deviceReady = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030` is a `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID` and could be retrieved at runtime via [HidD_GetHidGuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_gethidguid) call from Hid.dll.